# Parametrization of Lines and Curves

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, curves

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $C_1 : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C_2 : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be parametrizations of curves. In rigorous terms (unlike what is found in most calculus books), what does it mean for two parametrizations $C_1(t)$ and $C_2(t)$ to represent the same curve? My guess is that the images $C_1(D)$ and $C_2(D)$ are equal. Does this sound right?

Also, I am trying to prove that $L_1(t)$ and $L_2(s)$ are parametrizations of a line, then $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the same line if and only if they intersect at one point and their direction/slope vectors are parallel.

**EDIT:**

I have a related issue concerning equality of functions. To illustrate this issue, consider the simple example of showing that $r_1(t) = (3,-1,4) + t(8,12,-6)$ and $r_2(s) = (11,11,-2) + s(4,6,-3)$. Clearly if you let $t = \frac{s+2}{2}$, then $r_1(\frac{s+2}{2}) = r_2(s)$ every $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this imply they are the same curve? From my recollection, to functions $h,k : A \rightarrow B$ are equal if and only if $h(a) = k(a)$ for every $a \in A$, but perhaps I am confusing several concepts.

But this problem isn't merely about vector-valued functions. For instance, suppose that we have $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions, and suppose that through some deductions we showed that $f(x) = g(2x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Would this imply that $f = g$? I am thoroughly confused about these subtle points.

What is the root of my problem? How can I clear up this problem?

Comment: I would agree with your characterization of two parametrizations representing the same curve. As for your second statement, note that the forward direction is obvious and for the reverse direction, consider writing $L_1(t)$ and $L_2(s)$ component-wise as functions of $t$ and $s$ (e.g. $(m_1t+b_1, m_2t+b_2, \ldots, m_nt+b_n)$). Since the direction vectors are equal and the lines intersect at one point, you should be able to show that the $m_n$ and $b_n$ are equal in each component of $L_1(t)$ and $L_2(s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Strictly speaking, two functions $f_{1}:X_{1} \to Y_{1}$ and $f_{2}:X_{2} \to Y_{2}$ are equal precisely when:

- The domains are the same set: $X_{1} = X_{2}$.
- The codomains are the same set: $Y_{1} = Y_{2}$.
- The values are identical at each point: $f_{1}(x) = f_{2}(x)$ for all $x$ in $X_{1} = X_{2}$.

Consequently, your parametrized lines $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are *not equal as functions*.

Similarly, if $f(x) = g(2x)$ for all real $x$, it does not follow that $f$ and $g$ are equal as functions. (It *could* happen in this circumstance that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$, e.g., if $f$ and $g$ are constant.)

---

There is no universal definition of what it means to say two curves $C_{1}:[a_{1}, b_{1}] \to \Reals^{n}$ and $C_{2}:[a_{2}, b_{2}] \to \Reals^{n}$ are "the same". Definitions in use (in roughly decreasing order of likelihood) include:

1. One curve is an orientation-preserving reparametrization of the other: There exists an *increasing* bijection $\tau:[a_{1}, b_{1}] \to [a_{2}, b_{2}]$ such that $C_{1} = C_{2} \circ \tau$ as functions. (This is common when working with *vector* line integrals.)
2. One curve is a reparametrization of the other: There exists a continuous bijection $\tau:[a_{1}, b_{1}] \to [a_{2}, b_{2}]$ such that $C_{1} = C_{2} \circ \tau$ as functions. (This is common when working with *scalar* line integrals.)
3. The images are the same: $C_{1}([a_{1}, b_{1}]) = C_{2}([a_{2}, b_{2}])$. (I suspect this is uncommon, but it could be useful in, say, computer graphics.)

Conceivably, "the same" could mean "equal as functions", in which case the requirement would be much stronger: $a_{1} = a_{2}$, $b_{1} = b_{2}$, and $C_{1}(x) = C_{2}(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a_{1}, b_{1}] = [a_{2}, b_{2}]$. (Again, I suspect this is unusual.)

Answer (score 2):

> This is mainly to supplement Andrew D. Hwang's good answer.

Although $r_1 \neq r_2$ because $r_1(s) = r_2(s)$ doesn't hold for every $s$, what you wrote can be *framed* as an equality of functions if instead of comparing $r_2$ with $r_1$ we compare it with the *composition* of $r_1$ with the function $f(s) = \frac{s+2}{2}$ (that is, the function $r_1 \circ f$). If we do that, then we can say $(r_1 \circ f) = r_2$ as functions precisely because $(r_1 \circ f)(s) = r_1(\frac{s+2}{2}) = r_2(s)$ for every $s$.

Put another way: when we see $r_1 \left(\frac{s+2}{s} \right) = r_2(s)$, we're tempted to say, "Oh! Well then $r_1$ must equal $r_2$". But we're forgetting that when we say "$r_1$", we are really referring to the function $s \mapsto r_1(s)$. The function $s \mapsto r_1 \left(\frac{s+2}{2} \right)$ is *related* to $r_1$ (indeed, it is the *composition* of $r_1$ with the function $s \mapsto \frac{s+2}{2}$), but they are *not* the same function, and thus $(r_1 \circ f) = r_2$, but $r_1 \neq r_2$.